# Swing Matisse GUI - cannot add custom made bean to "Other components"

Tags: java, user-interface, data-binding, javabeans, matisse

I made a custom ValueObject class with properties (getters/setters) and I need this class for data binding of elements on form. So I want to drag it to "other components" on matisse editor so I can bind it - and nothing happens.... Any similar experiences? The same issue is happening both on NetBeans 6.5 and MyEclipse 7.0M2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method for adding components to the control palette is through the Palette Manager: right-click the palette (the 'other components' area for example) and select Palette Manager, then add it from the appropriate place (your current project by the sound of it.)

Your project needs to compile cleanly to do this.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I've concluded this, you can add only compiled class, it was even successfull once, but now I have regular class (which implements one interface) compiled, it wouldn't drop in. I put it first on custom palette area as widget and from there it went onto form.

Thanks, will try to find some workaround.. hope soon...

Answer (score 0):

found answer: MyEclipse is having problems with matisse forms when JRE is 1.6. In JRE 1.5 everything works fine. They said it will be fixed in MyEclipse 7.1